# QGIS 3 : Qt Signal emmitted when selecting a layer?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I am currently writing a QGIS 3 plugin. I would like to catch the signal emmited each time the user selects a new layer in the layer panel.

I have already searched in the QGIS API (`QgsProject`, `QgsLayerTree`, `QgsLayerTreeView`, ...)

`QgsLayerTreeView` has a signal `currentLayerChanged` but I cannot find how to connect `QgsLayerTreeView` to `QgsProject.instance()`.

Does anyone has an idea on what is the solution or at least where I can find some information?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect this signal to [iface](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a7e502c8c406538e6b518c4d93cc741d8) for example.

```
def currentLayerChanged(layer):
    print(layer.name())

iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(currentLayerChanged)
```

Or if you want make connection using `QgsLayerTreeView`

```
def onChange(layer):
  print("Current Layer: " + str(layer.name()))

# connect to the signal
view = iface.layerTreeView()
view.currentLayerChanged.connect(onChange)
```

Check the [lutraconsulting](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/) blog for more information. **Note** that this site use QGIS 2.4